# PyHive is Hanging on Connection -- Thrift_sasl appears to be the issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, hive, thrift

```
from pyhive import hive
import thrift_sasl
connection = hive.Connection(host='myhost', port=10000, database='local')
#hangs here

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('hive://myhost:10000/local')
logs = Table('mytable', MetaData(bind=engine), autoload=True)
#also hangs here
```

Both of these snippets will hang for me.

Hitting ctrl+c stops the execution here:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/apps/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 86, in __init__
self._transport.open()
File "thrift_sasl.py", line 74, in open
status, payload = self._recv_sasl_message()
File "thrift_sasl.py", line 92, in _recv_sasl_message
header = self._trans.readAll(5)
File "/apps/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
chunk = self.read(sz - have)
File "/apps/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 105, in read
buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am using Hive 0.12 and HiveServer2. I can connect to it using the python Hive library provided with Hadoop (.../hive/lib/py) but cannot do so with pyhive, which uses thrift_sasl.

Some people not using the thrift_sasl module suggest turning off SASL support in `hive-site.xml` via:

```
<property><name>hive.server2.authentication</name><value>NOSASL</value></property>
```

However after trying this the code still hanged with the same stack trace when I issued a `KeyboardInterrupt`.